# Docker for Windows で Gitlabのコンテナへブラウザからアクセスできない

Tags: docker, windows-10, wsl, gitlab

Docker for WindowsでGitlabのコンテナをスタートさせ、http://localhost にアクセスしても
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSEとなってしまい、ログイン画面が出てきません。
どうすればログイン画面にアクセスできますでしょうか?

行った操作としては
gitlab-configとgitlab-data のvolumeを作成する
下記のdocker-compose.ymlを実行する
という流れになります

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - 'gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab'
      - 'd:/Docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - 'gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab'
volumes:
    gitlab-data:
        external: true
    gitlab-config:
        external: true
```

環境は以下の通りです。

```
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829]

    REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
    nginx                      latest              719cd2e3ed04        2 days ago          109MB
    gitlab/gitlab-ce           latest              fcc1e4187c43        2 days ago          1.85GB
    hello-world                latest              fce289e99eb9        5 months ago        1.84kB
    docker4w/nsenter-dockerd   latest              2f1c802f322f        8 months ago        187kB

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                                 PORTS                                                          NAMES
bac53b2d2466        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   10 minutes ago      Up About a minute (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   docker_web_1
```

検証したこと
・portsを8080:80にしてhttp://localhost:8080 にアクセス
   →ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSEとなる
・nginxのコンテナをhttp://localhost で稼働させる
   →正常アクセスを確認
・https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/ のコマンドを、volume部分を作成したvolumeにして実行
   →ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled が発生したがコンテナは動作している
しかしERR_EMPTY_RESPONSEとなる